# jquery "change opacity script" works for one div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My script looks like this:

```
function progressBar() {
var percent = parseInt($('.current-speed').text());
var progressik = Math.floor((percent * 12 / 100));
var i = 0;
var time = 200;
    $('.current-speed-background').children().each(function () {
        var x = this;
        if (progressik > i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(x).animate({opacity: 1});
            }, (time * (i + 1)));
            i++;
        }
    });
```

}

This script works like progress bar (but you can know that from code).

I don't know why it works for one `<div class="speedometer-container">` out of four.

I've tried to put this function in `$('.speedometer).each(function() {}` etc. but it didn't help.

HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="speedometer-container">
                        <div class="speedometer-text">Wiedza</div>
                        <div class="speedometer">
                            <div class="current-speed-background">
                                <div class="speed speed1"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed2"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed3"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed4"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed5"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed6"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed7"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed8"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed9"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed10"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed11"></div>
                                <div class="speed speed12"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="current-speed">68%</div>
                            <div class="speedometer-details">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Details</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I would be very greatful if you fix this.

EDIT: I've fixed this. The problem was with :`var percent = parseInt($('.current-speed').text());` which takes value only once, so that's why this is 0 for the rest free containers.

Comment: Can you create a demo in Jsfiddle? Do you have multiple `speedometer-container`?

Comment: Yes, i have four speedometer containers. I'm trying to create demo in JsFiddle. Wait for my feedback.

Comment: If you want multiple independent progress bars on the same page you'll probably need to use a loop to process the top-level containers for each, and in that loop use `.find()` to get the relevant parts. Your current code uses `$('.current-speed').text()`, which will return the text of the *first* element with that class.

Comment: I have created a demo https://jsfiddle.net/5ew6xcu4/ where its giving every element. Check once

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. Let me create demo.

Comment: @nnnnnn i have created a basic demo which iterate each element when `speedometer-container` is multiple. OP is creating actual demo